# How to read a .mtl model file into MATLAB and visualise it?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, 3d-model, mtl-file

Does anyone know how to read a .mtl 3D model file into MATLAB and visualise it?
The .mtl file looks like following

```
newmtl body
Ns 51.0000
Ni 1.5000
d 1.0000
Tr 0.0000
Tf 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 
illum 2
Ka 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000
Kd 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000
Ks 0.5400 0.5400 0.5400
Ke 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
map_Ka body_diff.jpg
map_Kd body_diff.jpg
```

I tried using MTL_parser.m from https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39073-landsat-mss-tm-etm-metadata-mtl-parser?s_tid=srchtitle

Thanks

[image: Image for .mtl 3D model file]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to refer to this function here: https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27982-wavefront-obj-toolbox